# Permanent Cookie Contains Sensitive Session Information Laravel using Appscan security tool

Tags: laravel, security, bluemix-app-scan

I have scan the Laravel Project using AppScan tool, I am facing  security issue **Permanent Cookie Contains Sensitive Session Information** issue in AppScan Security Document.

[image]
Here is My Network information of Header:

```
Cache-Control: no-cache, private
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Encoding: gzip
Content-Length: 3692
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Date: Thu, 16 Aug 2018 06:01:02 GMT
Expires: 0
Pragma: no-cache
Server: Apache
Set-Cookie: XSRF-TOKEN=eyJpdiI6Ik9XVzJyOXRSZ0JkRnhaTXdkZlQzeVE9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoibUxEKzBLUHdCM2VwWVc4MzhPNjR3TmpcL2VZdWJXRjJmeVZklSaGtnb2RRblVBblpXNEVDS1wvMXExKzQwaE9NWlQwVFRpUTZiTHB3b1ZRMlcwZz09IiwibWFjIjoiNzhmMDg4MjUzN2YzMDA3MDg3MTJiOGNkMTQ4MTZlNWIyZWZiZTkxYjgwNzI1NzVmMzBmNWQyYjE1ZThjZDc3MiJ9; expires=Thu, 16-Aug-2018 08:01:02 GMT; Max-Age=7200; path=/; secure;HttpOnly;HttpOnly;Secure
Set-Cookie: laravel_session=eyJpdiI6InJpK3FNeHhTMGFEUUgxSGxKUkc1Rmc9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoieVRGaGpMcnJ3bnBrWCtOTzZcL2dzVFRKNDl5U29jUTlvb0tSZE54d2YxbTFvSHZ3TW5jc2FXcFwvcjhLaXlFN2R5eEo0Tlpoa1FxY0VUWlJ5bUjIjoiYTY2MjkwODU3YWQyMTFmZTJkNmZlMWUzMTgyYzk2NjA2OTBiMDgyODMzM2ZlZjg4NDE4MDBjZDFkYmIyNmEyMCJ9; expires=Thu, 16-Aug-2018 08:01:02 GMT; Max-Age=7200; path=/; secure; httponly;HttpOnly;HttpOnly;Secure
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains; preload
Vary: Accept-Encoding
X-Content-Security-Policy: allow 'self';
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
```

Also When i stop/ remove cookies from server side. I will block the csrf token.
How can i fix this security issue.?

Please Help!!
Thanks in Advance

Comment: Your CSRF-Token doesnt contains any sensitive data. Its used to prevent session stealing

Comment: @Phil795 Why appScan tool report this issue can explain please?

Answer (score 0):

I think it's a bug in the AppScan application. The message is already correct, session information is stored in the cookie. This serves to transfer this token with every request and to send back a new CSRF token afterwards.
Since the cookie has a Max-Age=7200; the cookie lives only 2 hours. Therefore, AppScan's statement that the cookie exists permanently is false.

And remember, with each request a new CSRF-Token is assigned to you, whereby the attacker would have to manipulate your locally sent request to be able to use this method.

Comment: I understand this flow. but can provide authenticate proof that's bug of appScan ?

Comment: I have scan the  project  Three times every time AppScan reported this issue

Comment: You can see the expiration time of the cookie. So AppScan is wrong about the persistent cookie

Comment: Open a ticket on AppScan and let the developers take care of the problem